# Aligning pictures while letting captions flow

Tags: html, css

I have multiple pictures I want to align in a row and need captions under each of them. I want to align the pictures and allow the captions to flow freely underneath the picture (some will take more lines than others). Learning from previous posts on SO, I found a way to limit the captions to the width of the pictures. I would expect the pictures to align, however, when I have multiple lines in the caption, the picture gets pushed up and all the captions align instead of the pictures, which I do not want.

HTML

```
<div class="wwapictures">
                <div id="wwaimg">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="wwa_dummy_picture.jpg">
                            <figcaption>Joe Smith<br>Co-Founder <br> Project Coordinator</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div id="wwaimg">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="wwa_dummy_picture.jpg">
                            <figcaption>Bob Joe <br> Co-Founder</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
     #wwaimg img{
        padding: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
    }

    .wwapictures #wwaimg {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .wwapictures figure {
        width: min-content;
    }
```

How can I align the pictures and still have captions of different sizes underneath each picture?

Comment: first of all ids should be unique in xml/html, so try making it a css class instead of id (`#wwaimg`)

Comment: the best solution with css is to set a min-height on CLASS (see previous comment) `.wwaimg` that is the same as the max height expected from the captions. This will aling everything and leave space if caption takes less lines

Answer (score 0):

Making my comments into an answer.

1. IDs should be unique in xml/html so `#wwaimg` is made into a css class `.wwaimg`
2. Adding a `min-height` css property on the figures which is same as the max height expected from the longest caption will align everything and leave space if caption takes less lines (assuming images are of the same height as they should be)

example (below solution uses `display:inline-block` and `float:left` to make the grid, but you can consider using [`flexbox` as well](https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/)):

```css
.wwapictures {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wwaimg img{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px; /* images should have same height*/
}
.wwaimg figcaption{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 70px;
}
.wwaimg {
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wwapictures">
 <figure class="wwaimg">
  <img src="wwa_dummy_picture.jpg" />
  <figcaption>Joe Smith<br>Co-Founder <br> Project Coordinator</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="wwaimg">
  <img src="wwa_dummy_picture.jpg" />
  <figcaption>Bob Joe <br> Co-Founder</figcaption>
</figure>
 <figure class="wwaimg">
  <img src="wwa_dummy_picture.jpg" />
  <figcaption>Joe Smith<br>Co-Founder <br> Project Coordinator</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="wwaimg">
  <img src="wwa_dummy_picture.jpg" />
  <figcaption>Bob Joe <br> Co-Founder</figcaption>
</figure>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, how can I make it responsive? When I shrink the page, the pictures shrink, which I don't want. I was thinking about using flex wrap, but would I have to recreate the grid using flexbox?

Comment: @NeilAgrawal, you can maintain a fixed width (so it does not shrink) easily. For example set `min-width: 1024px;` on `.wwapictures`. But this is not called responsive instead it is called fixed

Comment: @NeilAgrawal, for smaller screens (mobile) you can use [css media queries](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/02/media-queries-responsive-design-2018/) to make `.wwaimg {display:block;float:none;width:100%;}` that would be responsive design, but there are css grid frameworks available like `bootstrap` else you can make a a custom one